# Question about Sturge's Formula

Tags: combinatorics, statistics

I am trying to understand where Sturge's formula comes from. In the following equation, n is the number of observations and k represents the number of bins:

$ n = \displaystyle \sum_{i=0}^{k-1} \binom{k-1}{i}$

Sturge's formula is $k = 1 + 3.3log(n)$ where k represents the number of classes. I'm having trouble understanding the first equation. How do you know that the number of observations to be that value? To me this seems strange because the sum of every row in Pascal's triangle is a power of 2.

Answer (score 3):

The right hand side of the equation is
\begin{equation}
\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}{k-1\choose i}=\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}{k-1\choose i}(1)^{i}(1)^{k-1-i}=(1+1)^{k-1}=2^{k-1},
\end{equation}
by the Binomial Theorem. Taking logs on both sides of your first Eq., this leads to
\begin{equation}
(k-1)\log(2)=\log(n)\Rightarrow k=1+\frac{1}{\log(2)}\log(n)\approx 1+3.3\log(n)
\end{equation}
when taking $\log$ in base 10.

If one looks at the bins ($k-1$ of them), each one can be occupied or empty. In one example, the bins can be, for instance: $(o,e,o,\dots,o)$ where $o$ is occupied and $e$ is empty. The total number of such examples is $2^{k-1}$. When a bin is occupied, it may be that one or multiple observations fall in that bin.